# Sails.js - sails route with regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am working with sails 0.11.2. Here i am facing an issue with defining a route pattern that will start with '*/source/< anything goes here>/< must not contain .js extension at the end>*'

Regular Expression : `/^\/source.*(?<!.js)$/i` in java script in working fine, but when i am putting this in sails route.

Getting Error : `Invalid regular expression: /^r|\/^\/source\.(.*)(?<!\.js)$\/i\/?$/: Invalid group` .

Syntax in Route :

```
    'r|/^\/source.*(?<!.js)$/i' : {
    controller: 'pageController',
    action: 'pageAction'
  }
```

Please help me out, what is wrong and how to correct it?

Comment: can you save your regex as a variable, then use the variable as the route?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't support lookbehind `(?<!)` instead you can use negative lookahead `(?!)`

also the `/.../i` part shouldn't be in the regex string

so the valid expression should be :
`^\/source(.(?!\\.js$))*$`